# MYSQL - How to seperate values into columns - concat

Tags: mysql, sql, rows, multiple-columns, group-concat

Currently I have the following mysql code entered in phpmyadmin:

```
select Product_ID, group_concat(`Name` separator ',') as `Spec` 
from 
( 
select Product_ID, concat(`Name`, ':', 
group_concat(`Value` separator ',')) as `Name` 
from product_spec_list  
group by Product_ID, `Name` 
) tbl 
group by Product_ID
```

Which produces:

```
ID              Name
3   Shielded:0,Type:General Purpose
4   Shielded:0,Type:General Purpose
```

etc. with a long list of Product IDs with the Names and Values separated by : and ,.

How do I separate the Values into Columns named by 'Name'?

E.g.

```
ID Shielded      Type 
3     0     General Purpose 
4     0     General Purpose
```

There's about 40 different Names of values.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Google:  "mysql pivot" or "mysql dynamic pivot".  You need a dynamic pivot if you do not know the names of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but I am thinking something like this:

```
SELECT Product_ID AS `ID`
  , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(Name="Shielded", values, "") SEPARATOR "") AS `Shielded`
  , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(Name="Type", values, "") SEPARATOR "") AS `Type`
FROM
  (SELECT Product_ID, Name, GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR ',') AS values
   FROM product_spec_list
   GROUP BY Product_ID, Name
  ) AS subQ
GROUP BY Product_ID;
```